# Why does the "Low Quality Posts" show up in bold with a red button to its side?

Tags: support, bug

On the main page I've noticed that the Low Quality Posts under the Review drop-down menu sometimes shows up in bold font and with a red button to its left (see [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCKeFm.png)).

I expect there to be a question or answer in need of review, similar to when there is a grey circle to the left of a review queue, but perhaps with a higher priority given the difference in text font and circle color. However, when clicking on the low quality posts, I'm shown an empty queue. To make things more strange, I've only ever seen this happen to the low quality posts option.

I haven't seen any explanation of this anywhere. When does this happen? What does it mean? Is it just a weird bug?

[image: Screenshot of review drop-down menu]

Comment: Meta.SE: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226) And other posts [linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/302226) might be of interest, too.

Comment: Thanks @Martin that's helpful